# How to hide 'done' button on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, html

I am a starter on iOS development.

When I did loading html file that incude editable  tag on webkit view.

When I clicked div tag, I can see blink cursor. However, I can see 'done' button like below image. I don't want to see 'done' button line, I want to see only soft keyboard.

How can I hide 'done' button line?
Help me.[image: example]

Comment: have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140279/4056108), its in swift though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 - How to hide suggestion list above keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140116/ios-8-how-to-hide-suggestion-list-above-keyboard)